# What is the meaning of 省 in character breakdown

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I went on [zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B9%94) to find out about 乔. It says in the 详细 section,

> 会意。从夭，从高省，高亦声。夭，象人(大)行走的样子。本义:高

To my understanding, when a character is of the 会意 type, part of the character might be both phonetic and symbolic. So according to this, 乔 is derived from 夭 and 高, where 高 also provides a phonetic component (since the traditional script writes 喬). What I don't understand is the usage of 省 in 从高省.

It must mean something, or else my understanding of the description could simply be written as 从夭，高亦声, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「省」 means *graphically reduced*, i.e. not the entire structure of the component is incorporated.

The given definition largely comes from [*Shuōwén jiězì*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi):

> 《說文》：“喬，高而曲也。从夭，从高省。《詩》曰：‘南有喬木。’”

and since *Shuōwén jiězì* descriptions are linked to *Shuōwén* [small seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) shapes, by looking at these shapes the description would make more sense.

<kbd>[image: 喬]</kbd>
　　
<kbd>[image: 夭]</kbd>
　　
<kbd>[image: 高]</kbd>

Basically, *Shuōwén* thinks that 「喬」 is 「夭」 on top of 「高」 with its top 「亠」 removed, hence its description of the 「高」 part as *graphically reduced* (省).

---

> To my understanding, when a character is of the 会意 type, part of the character might be both phonetic and symbolic.

No, 「會意」 means *compound semantic*, that is, all components hint at meaning. If something is simultaneously a semantic and phonetic component, the literature normally says something like 「从Ｘ从Ｙ、Ｙ亦聲」, e.g.

> 《說文》：“墨，書墨也。从土，从黑，黑亦聲。”

---

By the way, that description

> 《說文》：“喬，高而曲也。从夭，从高省。《詩》曰：‘南有喬木。’”

is incorrect, 「夭」 does not give a meaning hint in 「喬」, and is the result of graphical corruption.

Comment: So does the Shuowen description contract its mistake from the fact that its definition for 喬 is  “高而曲也”? Does 曲 mean frail or misshapen or something like that in this case?

Comment: @DavidDong I didn't want to add details as that detracts from the main Q&A, if you're interested you could ask a separate question like "Glyph origins of 「喬」".